# VLC Crash when playing MKV files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, matroska

I'm not sure if the `mkv` file is corrupted, but when it is opened with VLC player, VLC loads up and displays nothing. Can't even close VLC after that. And also, VLC is running with 50% of the CPU. I have to use End Process to kill it.

How do I know if the file is corrupted? How do I solve this?

**info from mediainfo**

```
Format : Matroska 
File size : 69.4 MiB 
Duration : 21mn 48s 
Overall bit rate : 445 Kbps 
Encoded date : UTC 2009-11-20 18:33:49 
Writing application : mkvmerge v2.9.7 ('Tenderness') built on Jul 1 2009 18:43:35 
Writing library : libebml v0.7.7 + libmatroska v0.8.1 

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : High@L3.1 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, ReFrames : 2 frames 
Format settings, GOP : N=1 
Codec ID : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC 
Duration : 21mn 48s 
Width : 640 pixels 
Height : 352 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate : 23.976 fps 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Progressive 

Audio 
ID : 2 
Format : AAC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec 
Format profile : HE-AAC / LC 
Codec ID : A_AAC 
Duration : 21mn 48s 
Channel(s) : 2 channels 
Channel positions : Front: L R 
Sampling rate : 48.0 KHz / 24.0 KHz 
Compression mode : Lossy
```

Comment: Can you use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) and show us what it says about the file?

Comment: @slhck sure, downloading MediaInfo :) update soon.. thx

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you running the latest VLC? Are there any other MKV files in the same directory as suggested by the [VLC FAQ](http://wiki.videolan.org/Common_Problems#VLC_hangs_when_opening_Matroska_.28mkv.29_files)? Have you been able to play other MKVs before? You could install [K-Lite Codecs](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) and see if it works with another player.

Comment: yes, there are other MKV files that I can play... Just updated the VLC.. Installed K-Lite codec and now it's playing... thanks for your help @slhck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file not playing might be due to wrong information in the file itself. Looking at the content with [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) might reveal some issues.

There might be a common problem with other MKV files in the same directory. If you've tried the steps in the [VLC FAQ](http://wiki.videolan.org/Common_Problems#VLC_hangs_when_opening_Matroska_.28mkv.29_files) and it still doesn't work, it might be a codec issue.

You should also try to install the [K-Lite Codecs](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). They add support for many file types and video codecs to Windows.

Comment: K-Lite works!! :)

Comment: it's good to know this. Last time I test, VLC is the most lightweight one it works pretty fine on my aunt's computer which is quite old. The others didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in VLC main menu:

> Tools -> Preferences -> (click on "All" in the lower left corner) ->
>   Input/Codecs -> Demuxers -> Matroska

Uncheck the option `Preload directory`. This may cause problems if there are bad mkv files in the same directory in which the file you're trying to open is.